# Jquery mobile doesn't refresh CSS

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-mobile

I've got pages buid to handle jquery mobile.
Each page is stacked  like this, so it's a multipage

```
<div data-role="page" data-theme="d" id="page_login_index" data-cache="false" data-url="/clients/donqui/login/index" data-external-    page="true" tabindex="0" class="ui-page ui-page-theme-d"></div>
```

...

The problem is that when i navigate from one page to the another, the styles are not applied as expected and  i have to clock on the reload button of my browser to have a good result.

Since jqm doesn't care about the head tag, how can i do to load the styles correctly from one page to another ?

I don't understand, the links to the css sheets are exactly the same in the two pages

thanks

here's my demo site : http://com2clic.com/clients/donqui/

click on "boutique" and reload the page to see the expected result

Comment: hey can you make jsfiddle for this .? or provide some demo code

Comment: here's my demo site : http://com2clic.com/clients/donqui/
click on "boutique" and reload the page to see the expected result